# background image traveling past my page wrapper

Tags: css

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I want my background image to travel to the end of it's div and not outside of it.

'rule-btm.png' is going outside of #wrap-content.

```
#wrap-page{
  margin:auto; <-- This is to center the content on the page
  min-width:1170px;
  max-width:1280px;
}

#wrap-content{
  margin:0 5px; <--This is for a margin around my content
}

#tagline:after {
    background: url("rule-btm.png") repeat-x;
    content: "";
    float: left;
    height: 7px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    min-width: 1170px;
}
```

I am just curious so I'll ask. Would it be correct for me to float both #wrap-page and #wrap-content left?

---

```
<div id="tagline">
  <div></div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
I noticed that if I remove the min/max-widths and replace it with just `width`, I can get the background to travel where it needs to be.

Anyone?

Comment: Please add your html in the question. I think adding position relative in #tagline:after will fix your problem.

Comment: Sure, posting it now. Also, adding position:relative didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not Outside , It needs to be positioned

for example

```
background: url("rule-btm.png") top left repeat-x;
```

Comment: what are u trying to do with :after ?

I think u can omit it also

Comment: What I want is to have a minimum and maximum width on this website. THe min-width should be 1170 and the maximum should be 1280. So far, everything on the site is fluid for the 100px difference, however, the rules that repeat-x are either too short or too long. Your solution didn't seem to do anything. What is my next step?

Comment: I recommand add your code here, jsfiddle.net, then we can fix it for you